# Sort list by attribute of list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I know that there are several posts regarding sorts of python lists, but I tried a large bunch of things and didn't accomplish to get what I want.

My code:

```
    list = []
    things = re.findall('<a class="th tooltip" data-rel=.*? href="(.*?)".*?>   <img src="(.*?)" alt="(.*?)" .*?', content, re.DOTALL)
for url, image, name in things:
    list.append({'url': url, 'image': image, 'name': name})
```

Now I want to sort this list by name. I found several posts which stated to use `list.sort(key=)` but I don't know what I should use for the key. Everything I tried resulted in a `KeyError`.

I'm sorry if I'm duplicating an already solved post, but I can't find the proper solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a lambda function to map a list item `i` to `i['name']`, like so: `key=lambda i: i['name']`

Comment: Preferrably, `key=operator.itemgetter('name')`.

Comment: @bereal: Even better :)

Comment: @bereal use `operator.attrgetter('name')` or it won't work on objects that aren't subscriptable

Comment: @Patrick `attrgetter` won't work on dicts, and that's what we're dealing with in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a lambda expression , lambda expression would get the dictionary as parameter, and then you can return back the `name` element from the dictionary -

```
lst.sort(key=lambda x: x['name'])
```

Also, please do not use the `list` as name of the variable, it will overwrite the built-in `list` function, which may cause issues when trying to use `list(..)` function.

Comment: wow, thx.. I figured out that I sorted on the wrong place, therefore I got two sublists sorted as output. THX

Comment: Use `key=attrgetter('name')` for better performance (import attrgetter from operator)

Comment: `attrgetter` would not work in this , as we are working with dictionaries inside a list.
But if you were going to do `getattr(x, 'name')` or `x.name` as key , then `attrgetter` would work . But don't really commend trying to optimize, unless you know this part is the bottleneck of the program.